# Percentage Plus and Minus

Tags: sql, t-sql

Having an issue calculating money after percentages have been added and then subtracting , I know that 5353.29 + 18% = 6316.88 which I need to do in my tsql but I also need to do the reverse and take 18% from 6316.88 to get back to 5353.29 all in tsql, I might have just been looking at this too long but I just cant get the figures to calculate properly, any help please?

Comment: Also, this isn't a SQL problem -- this is just mathematics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6316.88 is 118%, so to get back you need to divide 6316.88 by 118, then multiply by 100.

```
(6316.88/118)*100=5353.29
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newVal = 5353.29(1 + .18)

origVal = newVal/(1 + .18)
```

Answer (score 0):

To Add n% to X

Result = X * ( 1 + (n / 100.0))

To do the reverse

X = Result / ( 1 + (n / 100.0))